# Android's BluetoothGatt API is automatically discovering services after connecting and breaks afterwards

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, gatt, service-discovery

I'm trying to implement a BLE feature in my Android application and I'm facing some trouble using the `BluetoothGatt` api.

The actual problem is the dreading status `129 (GATT_INTERNAL_ERROR)` every time I call `mGatt.discoverServices()`. After debugging this, I noticed that the service discovery packets doesn't even leave the Android phone (By looking at the hci snoop log).

I also noticed that when calling `mGatt = mPeripheral.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback)`, a lot more is happening than the actual connect. When I call this method, the API also asks my peripheral for it's services and characteristics after connecting.

I guess it's the expected behaviour, despite that it is not documented. However, I think that it causes a problem in my case, because the 128 bit Service UUID I want to access on my peripheral doesn't seem to fit into the standard MTU.

In my own code, I request an MTU change before calling `mGatt.discoverServices()`, but if it's happening automatically I don't know how to control it.

My current theory is that the implicit service discovery fails because the desired Service doesn't fit into the packets and it's somehow messing up the `BluetoothGatt` instance so that it cannot start a new discovery afterwards.

Any input on this matter is appreciated, but some actual questions are:

- Can I prevent `mGatt = mPeripheral.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback)` from also discovering Services?
- Can I change the MTU Size before it's automatically discovering the services? I have tried to request an mtu change (`mGatt.requestMtu(256)`) immediately after getting the `BluetoothGatt` instance, but it doesn't change anything.
- Can I "repair" the `BluetoothGatt` instance before my own call to `discoverServices()`, so that it will actually be performed?

Some notes:

- I have full access to the Peripheral and can see all the communication between them.
- I have implemented the feature in my corresponding iOS app already using Core Bluetooth and everything works as expected (against the same peripheral of course).

Comment: All GATT discovery procedures fit in standard/minimum MTU, even for 128bit UUIDs. Your problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: @Nipo I will look into that, thank you